How can I open a jammed key from a lock?
My key has been either jammed/ or got broken inside the lock, I tried multiple tricks to pull out the key, but none of the methods worked. Would appreciate any advice that can help me resolve my problem.

A professional locksmith may have specialized tools which can hook and pull in the key. Depending on where the break occurred it may be necessary to lift pins out of the way at the same time.
Alternatively, if you can get into the house another way, it may be faster/easier to disassemble the lock and push the key out from the back. Again this may require lifting pins out of the way unless the break is right at the face of the lock.
Note that if you can dismount the lock and take it to a locksmith, this may be considerably cheaper than having the locksmith come to you. (Or may not; in my area many other visits are now working almost entirely from a van or truck rather than having storefronts.)

Or, barring that, simply replace the lock set entirely, especially if it's aging.

@FreeMan: True enough. And a locksmith can set the new lock to respond to the same keys as the old lock so you don't have to replace them all, if desired. But it seemed worth answering the question as asked.
